# Insert into Table after processing Week Number SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I have the following table:

```
Date          Number
-----------------------------
2018-01-01    10
2018-01-04    5
2018-01-10    10
2018-01-20    5
2018-02-01    8
2018-02-03    2
2018-02-28    10
```

I want to have the following result:

```
WeekNumber     Year      SumOfNumber
-----------------------------------------------
1              2018      15
2              2018      10
3              2018      5
5              2018      10
9              2018      10
```

Week day Start from `Monday to Sunday`.
The result should be inserted into a Table.

Does anyone have an idea for this?
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ISO_WEEK` in `DATEPART()` function

```
select 
       DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, date) WeekNumber, year(date) Year, sum(Number) SumOfNumber
from table
group by DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, date),  year(date)
```

Comment: Wow, this is great!